# Get year from unknown date format

Tags: c#

I am pulling data from musicbrainz server, and the date comes back in random formats, it is either empty, null, includes only the year, or has formats such as:

```
01-01-2022 
2022-01-01
01//01/2022
2022
```

I tried

```
DateTime.Parse(date).Year;
```

It gives me an error on strings that return just the year.

Comment: Apply ToString and add RegEx for 4 digits? You would still need a null check of course.

Comment: It's no problem finding an answer for the 4 formats you listed. But if someone writes that code for you, you'll still not be happy, since you didn't provide an exhaustive list of possible formats. Also, you did not specify what year you want in case of `null`, empty string etc. Before you start coding, define the requirements. Always.

Comment: Also, first three dates shown are ambiguous - does day or month come first?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: not very ambiguous if you're looking for the year only.

Comment: You shouldn't try to parse into a `DateTime` object. Regex to do it should be pretty straightforward though. e.g. `int.Parse(Regex.Match(date, "\\d{4}").Value)`

Comment: Thomas, those are the only formats, and yes I have a null check prior. David, I will try the regex method, ty.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Good point!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't advise using `DateTime` parsing for this since some of these formats aren't complete. However, if you really wanted to, you could use `ParseExact` and pass in multiple format strings. For example:

```
var formats = new [] 
{
    "dd-MM-yyyy", // Assuming this is correct based on your example
    "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "dd//MM/yyyy",
    "yyyy"
};

var parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var year = parsedDateTime.Year;
```

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression to search for 4 consecutive numbers. For example:

```
var yearString = Regex.Match(date, "\\d{4}").Value;
var year = int.Parse(yearString);
```

Note that none of the above are robust and should have error handling etc.